# Where can I get Windows 7 drivers for a Dell XPS 1730?

Tags: drivers, dell-xps

I can only find Vista drivers on the official Dell site.

I have managed to download the video driver directly from the manufacturer but I still need:

- Base System Driver: Intel Core Duo T9300 (This might not be that important, but Windows gives me an error in the device manager)
- Integrated Sound Blaster Audigy ADVANCED HD  (Once again I have a work-around by using an external USB soundcard from Steelseries)

Comment: The Vista drivers should work fine, Windows Vista and 7 both use the WDM (Windows Driver Model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vista drivers will work.

For the Base System Device use the **Ricoh** card reader driver (under 'Chipset' on the download page).

Answer (score 0):

Remember to make sure that you download the correct version of the software.  I.E. 64bit drivers for 64 bit Windows!